# Generate random decimals

Tags: objective-c, random, decimal

I'd like to know how to generate random decimals between 0 and 1. I tried using arc4random() but it only generates integers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(float)random()/RAND_MAX
```

Comment: UGH! That's an ugly hack.. :-P

Comment: @ach: The maximum number `rand()` will return + 1.